# How to create global variable or state for class component in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-redux

I want to use a global variable/state that can use in multiple class components in my app.

When I am running any method from particular components than at the start of it method I want to change the variable/state value from null to something and after the end of the method again set the value variable/state to null.

Along with that I also want to access the changed variable/state value in another component which is on another file to take some decisions on that changed value.

How to do that any idea?

Note: My application is built using class components and react-redux.

GlobalStateProvider.tsx

```
import React, { createContext, useState, useContext, Dispatch, SetStateAction } from "react";

export interface GlobalStateInterface {
  abcstring: string;
  xyzstring: string;
}

const GlobalStateContext = createContext({
  state: {} as Partial<GlobalStateInterface>,
  setState: {} as Dispatch<SetStateAction<Partial<GlobalStateInterface>>>,
});

const GlobalStateProvider = ({
  children,
  value = {} as GlobalStateInterface,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  value?: Partial<GlobalStateInterface>;
}) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(value);
  return (
    <GlobalStateContext.Provider value={{ state, setState }}>
      {children}
    </GlobalStateContext.Provider>
  );
};

const useGlobalState = () => {
  const context = useContext(GlobalStateContext);
  if (!context) {
    throw new Error("useGlobalState must be used within a GlobalStateContext");
  }
  return context;
};

export { GlobalStateProvider, useGlobalState };
```

page.tsx

```
import { useGlobalState, GlobalStateInterface } from "../../app/GlobalStateProvider";

const { setState } = useGlobalState();
const { handleSubmit } = useForm();
const submitFunction = (data: Partial<GlobalStateInterface>) => {
     setState((prev) => ({ ...prev, ...data }));
}

export class className extends React.Component{
 render() {
 return (
      <>
      <input accept=".csar,.yaml" id="file" min={1} max={1} multiple={false} type="file" name="abc" onChange={e => { handleFileChange(e)}} /> 
       <label htmlFor="file">
       <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(submitFunction)}> */}
         <Button className = {inputUploadButton} component="span" variant="primary" type="submit" isSmall onClick={e => e.stopPropagation()}>
           <Tooltip
             key={`Upload`}
             content={<div >Upload</div>}
           >
             <UploadIcon />
           </Tooltip>
         </Button>
       </form>
       </label></>
     }
}
export default className;
```

Page2.tsx

```
import { useGlobalState } from "../../../app/GlobalStateProvider";
class className2 React.Component {
  render() {
   const { state } = useGlobalState();
    return (
      <>
        <ToolbarItem>
         { console.log(state.abcstring)
          }
          { state.savinfmodelmessage === "Saving" ?
            <>
              <Title sizes={'sm'} headingLevel={'h6'}>
                operation in progress...
              </Title>
            </>:
            <></>
          }
        </ToolbarItem>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default className2;
```

When I am trying to yarn build then it gives an error as follows:

```
error  React Hook "useGlobalState" cannot be called in a class component. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
```

Comment: have you tried doing anything in code which is not working? post that info too!

Comment: Use react context, or something like redux

Comment: That would be a way to solve this problem using hooks, but you can only call hooks from class components. As a result of this, you'll have to either convert your components to function components, or replace the hooks with class APIs.

Comment: Can you please guide me on how to convert react hook to class APIs? @NickMcCurdy

Comment: You can use the [context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) in class components. However, it would be better to use function components so you could continue using these hooks, especially since that's what React Redux uses now.

Answer (score 0):

Use Redux for global state management.